# iOS: Is this the proper way to create a directory in Application Support to store my SQL file?

Tags: ios, objective-c, path, filesystems

I have a sqlite file that I am trying to store in Application Support Folder. I am using the following code to create the directory.

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSApplicationSupportDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *applicationSupportDirectory = [paths firstObject];
NSError *err;
NSString *dataPath = [applicationSupportDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/Email"];
if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:dataPath])
            [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:dataPath withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:nil error:&err]; //Create folder

NSString  *dataBasePath = [applicationSupportDirectory stringByAppendingString:@"/Email/Email.sqlite"];
```

This is the printed result when I NSLog dataBasePath

> /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/8A40E5A9-EEE6-46EF-B71F-36C9A00D5996/Library/Application
>   Support/Email/Email.sqlite

Is this correct way of creating the directory to store my sql file in Application Support? I have to use Application Support so the user can't mess with it (I use file share so document directory is out of the question) and the OS shouldn't be able to mess with it either. I just need to be sure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's close but not quite right. Don't put the `/` before `Email`. You want to pass `YES` to `withIntermediateDirectories`. And the final path should use `dataPath` and `stringByAppendingPathComponent`.

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSApplicationSupportDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *applicationSupportDirectory = [paths firstObject];
NSString *dataPath = [applicationSupportDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Email"];
if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:dataPath]) {
    NSError *err;
    if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:dataPath withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:&err]) { //Create folder
        NSLog(@"Unable to create folder at %@: %@", dataPath, err);
    }
}

NSString  *dataBasePath = [dataPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Email.sqlite"];
```

Comment: This works, but I don't get this  if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:dataPath withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:&err]) { //Create folder
        NSLog(@"Unable to create folder at %@: %@", dataPath, err);
    }

Comment: If there is an error trying to create any needed folders, that code prints out the error. Your code never checked to see if the creation succeeded and it ignored any error. My code does proper result checking and error logging.